# How to get Effective Rate?

Tags: finance

When googling for Effective rates, i'm getting a different result for the formula compared to what we are using in our current company.

Google Result:
Effective Annual Rate(EAR) = ((1+i/n)^n)-1

where i = annual interest rate

n = Compounding Periods

For Example for Quarterly
EAR = ((1+.1/4)^4)-1

EAR = 10.381%

Company Formula
Effective Rate = ((1 + Nominal_rate/Npery)^Npery)-1
where

Nominal_rate = annual rate / 12 if monthly; annual rate / 4 if quarterly

Npery = 12/x where x = 12 if Monthly; x = 4 if Quarterly

For Example
For a Quarterly payment frequency and a 10% rate

Nominal Rate = 10%/4 = 2.5%

When using the company formula

Npery = 12/4(since Quarterly) = 3

Effective Rate = ((1 + 0.025/3)^3)-1

Effective Rate = 2.521%

**The question is, which one is more appropriate to use?**

Answer (score 0):

I do not understand your implementation of the company method.

If the nominal annual rate is $10\%$ and gets applied as $2.5\%$ charged at the end of each quarter (so four times a year) then I would have thought

- `Npery` $=4$
- `Nominal_rate` $=10\%=0.1$
- `Nominal_rate/Npery` $=2.5\%=0.025$
- `EAR =((1 + Nominal_rate/Npery)^Npery)-1` $= ((1 + 0.1/4)^4)-1 \approx 0.10381 =10.381\%$

as in your initial calculation.  An Effective Annual Rate of about a quarter of the nominal annual rate is implausible.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply.
Npery as per formula was = 12 / x... where x is 12 if Monthly and 4 if Quarterly
in my case since quarterly, 12 / 4 = 3. Npery = 3